# SFDX Package Version List command returns 431 Error

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, list, versioning, sfdx-error

When I execute the command `sfdx force:package:version:list` I receive a message

`<h1>Bad Message 431</h1><pre>reason: Request Header Fields Too Large</pre>`

I don't understand why I started receiving such a message if the same command executes successfully a moment ago?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when the total number of package versions becomes too large, that is more than 700, this commands starts failing with such an error.

As an option, some parameter should be passed to the command to limit the resulting scope size, for example,

```
sfdx force:package:version:list -c 1
```

to return also the package versions created today.

Another option is to run some script to delete beta versions which might not be really needed anymore

```
dh=$1
echo $dh
for pvId in $(sfdx force:package:version:list -p $2 -v $dh --json | jq '.result[] .SubscriberPackageVersionId' -r)
do
    sfdx force:package:version:delete -n -p $pvId -v $dh
done
```